# JQuery click() function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, Below is my JQuery code. I'm simply trying to change the `inAddMode` boolean variable to the opposite of what it is when my button with id `add_button` is pressed. The alert box is there for testing, but it never triggers when I press `add_button` button. Any ideas why this is not working. `add_button` is an image, Would that affect it?

```
var inAddMode = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add_button').click(function(){
            inAddMode = !inAddMode;
        alert(inAddMode);
    });
    //For Adding events on the map
        $('#map').click(function(e){
            if(inAddMode){
                var img = $('<img src="img/map_pin.png" />');
                var mapWidth = $("#map_img").width();
                var mapHeight = $("#map_img").height();

                //Must keep the pixel ratio of original image constant
                var mapPinWidth = mapWidth*(0.08);
                var mapPinHeight = mapPinWidth;

                var offsetLeft = mapPinWidth/2;
                var offsetTop = mapPinHeight;

                img.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    width: mapPinWidth,
                    height: mapPinHeight,
                    left: e.pageX-offsetLeft,
                    top: e.pageY-offsetTop,
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                });
                $("#map").append(img);
            //Now make the app take you to the event creation page
            }
        });


    //end of addMode
});
```

Full HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <!--<img src="img/map_north.PNG" style="width:  100%;height: 45%;">
    <img src="img/map_south.PNG" style="width: 100%; height: 45%;">
    -->
    <div id="map">
        <img id="map_img" src="img/map.PNG" style=" position: relative; width: 100%;height: auto; border-style: solid"> 


            <script>
                var mapWidth = $('#map_img').width();
                var mapHeight = $('#map_img').height();
                var addSignWidth = mapWidth*(0.04);
                var addSignHeight = addSignWidth;

                var addSign =  $('<img src="img/add_img.png" >');
                var offsetLeft = addSignWidth;
                var offsetTop = addSignHeight;

                addSign.css({
                    id: 'add_button',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    width: addSignWidth,
                    height: addSignWidth,
                    left: mapWidth-offsetLeft - mapWidth*(0.001),
                    top:  mapHeight*(0.04) ,
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                });

                $("#map").append(addSign);

            </script>

            <!---<img src="img/add_img.png" style=<script>getAddButtonInfo()</div>>-->
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show your html - are there any console errors?

Comment: Have you checked putting debugger in your Click function? or any error in browser Console?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I believe `click` events are detectable only on links, buttons and that sort of clickable stuff. If you want to make an image clickable, wrap it inside an anchor element `<a>`: `<a href="#" id="add_button"><img ... /></a>` and then add the `event.preventDefault();` to your jQuery event so the anchor doesn't follow its `href`.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)? @AlejandroIván Nope, (almost) all visible elements are clickable.

Comment: write alerts to check whether it goes tthere

Comment: check that you are using correct id 'add_button', open the view source of the page and confirm that. Also make sure it is not a typo mistake.

Comment: i have seen where you created the img dyamically with jquery and also gave it attributes with .css jquery. cover your script in the HTML part with document.ready since you are using jQuery

Comment: I added the document.ready and it still wasn't working

Comment: can you pls make a fiddle of your code and post i will make it work

Comment: never mind check my updated answer and see the solution to your problem and how i did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#add_button')` doesn't contain any elements when the DOM is ready. This is because you haven't set `id` for the image button. Instead you've this code:

```
addSign.css({
    id: 'add_button',
          :
}
```

But setting `id` property in CSS rule doesn't set `id` of an element. You need this instead:

```
addSign.prop('id', 'add_button');
```

Notice also, that the position properties you've set need an unit.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks bunches! So is id not actually a css property?

Comment: Yep, `id` is not a CSS property. You can link an element to CSS rules with an `id` selector though, but that's a different feature.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're adding `#add_button` dynamically? In that case you should use delegation, for example

```
$('body').on('click', '#add_button', function(){
  inAddMode = !inAddMode;
  alert(inAddMode);
});
```

Comment: I am adding it dynamically. I put the html up. But even using this method it isn't working. Any other ideas?

Comment: As been said below, you forgot to add id to your `#map_img`

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   //initial values started here
    var mapWidth = $('#map_img').width();
    var mapHeight = $('#map_img').height();
    var addSignWidth = mapWidth*(0.04);
    var addSignHeight = addSignWidth;

    var addSign = $('<img src="img/map_pin.png" />'); //Equivalent: $(document.createElement('img'))
    addSign.attr('id', "add_button");
    addSign.css({'cursor': 'pointer' });
     //i remove these from the above code which seem to move the element of the screen with left and top attribute given to it
    //left: mapWidth-offsetLeft - mapWidth*(0.001),
        //top:  mapHeight*(0.04);
    //'position':'absolute';
    //'width': addSignWidth,
    //'height': addSignWidth,
    var offsetLeft = addSignWidth;
    var offsetTop = addSignHeight;
    
    $("#map").append(addSign);
    // initial values ended here


    
    var inAddMode = false;
    $('#add_button').click(function(){
        inAddMode = !inAddMode;
        alert(inAddMode);
    });
    //For Adding events on the map
        $('#map').click(function(e) {
            if(inAddMode){
                var img = $('<img src="img/map_pin.png" />');
                var mapWidth = $("#map_img").width();
                var mapHeight = $("#map_img").height();

                //Must keep the pixel ratio of original image constant
                var mapPinWidth = mapWidth*(0.08);
                var mapPinHeight = mapPinWidth;

                var offsetLeft = mapPinWidth/2;
                var offsetTop = mapPinHeight;
                img.css({                  
                    'cursor': 'pointer',
                    'position': 'absolute',
                });
                // i did remove these again from the code above which is these
                //'position': 'absolute',
                //'width': mapPinWidth,
                //'height': mapPinHeight,
                //'left': e.pageX-offsetLeft,
                //'top': e.pageY-offsetTop,
                img.insertAfter($("#map"));
                //to see the img  i added background-color to see the last result well
            }
        });
     
    //end of addMode
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--<img src="img/map_north.PNG" style="width:  100%;height: 45%;">
    <img src="img/map_south.PNG" style="width: 100%; height: 45%;">
    -->
    <div id="map">
        <img id="map_img" src="img/map.PNG" style="position: relative; width: 100%;height: 50px; border-style: solid"> 
        
    </div>
```

**NOW WHAT DID I DO**

These are changes i made to make your code work

1. i remove the codes script tag in your html part which you posted and put them together with other JQuery codes, which was only a choice not necessary important but to organize.
2. i editted the `addSign.css()`, removing only `left`, `top`, `height` and `width`, which made the `addSign` wonder off the screen
3. i gave `addSign` id attribute which is `add_button`
4. `$("#map).click()` function, i also editted the `img.css()`, removing `left`, `top`, `width` and `height` which also made the result off the screen.

Now the problem is solved and the code is working. those css atrributes you still add them but this time make your calculations correctly so you will be able to see your solution.

Comment: A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. He is using jquery so it changes alot

Comment: yeah it is but assuming he tries the .click function with pure javascript and no jquery it will work

Comment: Please tell me what is the difference between `{prop: value}` and `{"prop": value}`???

Comment: propertyname is not a variable rather a css property.  so accessing the css property should be enclosed with quotes

Comment: without quotes it wont work,  try it out and you will see for yourself

Comment: I really don't know what you're talking [about](https://jsfiddle.net/L3p1qnu2/). The argument passed to `.css` is an object literal, it doesn't need property names being quoted (but allows it). If you passed a string, then quoting would be mandatory.

Comment: Oh yes seems you are right, i have editted my answer, i got that from w3school.. Thanks